# Replace blank cells with string contents

Tags: vba, excel

I am needing to populate some blank cells in a specific range with a string i.e. "Green" Unfortunately I don't know the last row number as this may not be populated and could change every time I run the scripting as I am pulling data from one worksheet into another in a specific format.

I am searching for the last row number on a column I know will always have data in that cell, This is the part of the scripting I am running below for the question I am asking, I am searching for an empty cell and replacing it with the word 'Greens'.  I am not getting any errors it just doesn't work so not sure where my logic has gone wrong.

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row


With Range("AS22:AU" & LastRow)

         .Replace what:=" ", Replacement:="Greens"

End With
```

Comment: @ScottCraner that didn't work, still not getting anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this;

```
.Replace what:=" ", Replacement:="Greens"
```

use this;

```
.Replace what:="", Replacement:="Greens"
```

If your cells include fake blanks then use this before;

```
Columns("AS:AU").TextToColumns Destination:=Range("AS1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1)
```

Comment: This does not work.
use this;
.Replace what:="", Replacement:="Greens"

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for cells with a single space instead of completely empty. Try:

```
Dim r as range
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For each r in Range("AS22:AU" & LastRow)
     if r.value2 = vbnullstring then r.value2 = "Greens"
Next r
```

Comment: I have tried this and I get a compile error when using your code.  It does not like the End With.  I have tried Exit For but does not seem to like this as well.  Any suggestions??

Comment: Sorry, my bad. That should be a "Next r", not an "End with". I edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Just get the blank cells:

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row 
Range("AS22:AU" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Value = "Green"
```